# Simple Probability question from observing a graph out of Henk Tijims- Understanding Probability book

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Good evening,
The graph shown below is in reference to the text as follows:

The highlighted text below in bold is what I don't understand. How was this deduced from the graph. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance

"For this figure, we have
simulated 100,000 repetitions of a match between two players A and B. The
match consists of a series of 20 tosses of a fair coin, where player A scores
a point each time heads comes up and player B scores a point each time tails
comes up. Figure 2.2 gives the simulated distribution of the number of times
that player A is in the lead during a series of 20 tosses. The height of the bar
on each base point k gives the simulated value of the probability that player
A is k times in the lead during the 20 tosses. Here the following convention
is made. If there is a tie after the final toss, the final toss gets assigned as
leader the player who was in the lead after the penultimate toss (on the basis
of this convention, the number of times that player A is in the lead is always
even).
Looking at the simulation results, it appears that player A has a probability
of 17.5% of being in the lead during the whole match. **Put differently, the player
in the lead after the first toss has approximately a 35% probability of remaining
in the lead throughout the 20-toss match"**

[image]

Comment: Since there are two players, each of whom is equally likely to be in the lead for the entire match, there is $2 \cdot 17.5\% = 35\%$ chance that a player is in the lead for the entire match.

Comment: Thank you!! This makes sense